# How can I hide my gmail.smtp password when using SMTP.js?

Tags: javascript, smtp, email-client

I want to send an email from my website. It's a static website so I only have JavaScript. Gmail has an SMTP service that is free to use and allows to send messages from the browser using smtp.js.
The problem is that anyone can look at the source of my website and find my gmail SMTP password. Can I somehow hide it?

Comment: Do you use https?

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable 2-factor authentication from security.google.com and then there will be available option of app passwords.From there you can generate temporary app password for gmail and use that in smpt js. It just works fine in my case.

Comment: Can you support with an example please?

Answer (score 0):

You could use JWT. Here is a link that will help you [JWT Tutorial](https://medium.com/@maison.moa/using-jwt-json-web-tokens-to-authorize-users-and-protect-api-routes-3e04a1453c3e)